# Command line - Awk command for Windows

Tags: r, windows, awk, command-line, pipe

I have a CSV file with millions of rows. I would like to open a connection to the file and filter unnecessary rows before opening it in R. To detail, I would like to import every 30th row starting at the second row.

I am operating on a Windows machine. I know the following command achieves the desired result on an Apple; however, it doesn't work on my Windows machine.

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{i++;if (i%30==2) print $1}' < test.csv
```

In R, if I ran this code on an Apple, I would get the desired result:

```
write.csv(1:100000, file = "test.csv")
file.pipe <- pipe("awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{i++;if (i%30==2) print $1}' < test.csv")
res <- read.csv(file.pipe)
```

Clearly, I know nothing about Windows CLI, so could someone translate this awk command to Windows language for me and possibly explain how the translation achieves the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

### UPDATE:

So I have downloaded Git and have successfully been able to complete this task using Git command line, but I need to implement it in R because I have to do this task on thousands of files. Anyone know how to make R run this command through Git?

Comment: Idk if that is what you are looking for, but tools like [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) give you most of the Linux/ cmd line functionality on a Windows machine. So if this is a one-off thing that might be all you need

Comment: What do you mean by "windows cli"? Either you have `awk` installed (via [git-for-windows](http://gitforwindows.org/), cygwin (as patrick mentioned), or native installs), or you need to find a different program. BTW, a little shorter: `awk 'NR%30==2'` ... I just found [this](https://superuser.com/a/396556/402193) today, coincidence?

Comment: So if I downloaded cygwin, this command would work? Is it that simple? @patrick

Comment: A lighter-weight solution is git-for-windows, which includes `awk`, `sed`, and several other great small tools like that.

Comment: 'course, you could always just go straight to [`gawk` for gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), but if you want `git` and/or other tools, having them all together is convenient.

Comment: Can someone inform me? Pardon my ignorance on the subject, but what it git? Is it a program? Why does this command work on an Apple, but not a Windows? Do these commands come preinstalled on Apple?

Comment: Version control. Depending on your history, you may have heard of RCS, CVS, subversion, mercurial, bit bucket ... if not, well, all I can say that it saved me on my thesis when I had to track down a change made three months previously.

Comment: @ConnorGibbs Cygwin emulates the standard Linux shell on a Windows machine, i.e. swk should work just like you are used to. Most Unix commands such as `awk` will not work in the Windows shell or have different syntax, so I found cygwin easier to handle. However, I think they have improved the shell.

Comment: A combination of `list.files` (to get the file names), a `for` loop (to iterate over the files), and `system`, you should be able to do it.

Comment: The first two steps are done. The last step I still am struggling with. @r2evans Could you please post how one could use system() with the test.csv example? To start, I have tried running something simple like `system('echo \'hello world!\' ')` it errors out with a status 127, but `shell('echo \'hello world!\' ')` works. Why? What is the difference? If you could exemplify this for the test.csv file that would be a big help.

Comment: I'd suggest something as simple as `system("awk NR%30==1 test.csv > out.csv"); x <- read.csv("out.csv")`

Comment: I tried running the above and it returned a status 127. I tried the same with shell(), and it errored out as well; however, it created a blank out.csv file. You can find the errors [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h0OJ-MyhVDYDYJBmgME-lPqUquLRKO3T/view?usp=sharing). Any idea what may be coming on? @r2evans Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: If `Sys.which("awk")` returns an empty string (that's my guess), then it means `awk` is not in your path.

Comment: It does return an empty string. How can I fix this? What do you mean "not in your path?" @r2evans

Comment: Try `system("C:/PROGRA~1/Git/usr/bin/awk.exe ...")`. And then uninstall and reinstall git-for-windows and enable the third option of "add to path". Then close and restart R.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165532/discussion-between-connor-gibbs-and-r2evans).

Comment: Just suggesting the `readr` package. You can read chunks of a file, for example 10000 lines and do your filtering (any kind of filtering) on this subset and add it to you final data frame. `readr` functions are pretty fast in my opinion and the reading chunks option gives the possibility to filter before loading the complete data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
write.csv(1:100000, file = "test.csv")
file.pipe <- pipe("awk \"BEGIN{i=0}{i++;if (i%30==2) print $1}\" test.csv")
res <- read.csv(file.pipe)
```

On windows the programline of awk need to be surrounded by double quotes. They are escaped because of the other double quotes on the same  line.

Also the '<' before the input file is not needed (an I doubt that it is needed on an Apple.)